# combine non-empty columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe with unique rows, where only one row will have a value for any given column, how can I merge the rows into a single row.

Example:

```
sample = {'IBM': {0: np.NAN, 1: 5.333333333333333},
          'MSFT': {0: np.NAN, 1: 1.0},
          'ORCL': {0: np.NAN, 1: 2.0},
          'INDUSTRY': {0: 3.7999999999999998, 1: np.NAN}}

df_sample = pd.DataFrame(sample)
```

`df_sample` will contain 2 rows, with non-overlapping values. Any column in a given row that has a value will contain a NaN in any other row.

How can I flatten this out into a single row:
IE,

```
expected = {'IBM': {0: 5.333333333333333},
            'MSFT': {0: 1.0},
            'ORCL': {0: 2.0},
            'INDUSTRY': {0: 3.7999999999999998}}

df_expected = pd.DataFrame(expected)
print df_expected
```

Comment: would `df_sample.bfill().drop_duplicates()` work for your case?

Comment: Yes, Thank you. That seems to get me going in the right direction. It returns 2 rows still, but the first row is what I'm looking for, so I guess I can just slice off the top row. Thank you